# How to make local .command Terminal script?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, command

I created a `.command` file that runs a certain command `java -jar myApp.jar` in the Terminal, however it doesn't work because it first needs to `cd` into a certain directory.

Is there a way to make the `.command` file automatically go to the address where the `.command` file currently is, and execute the command from there?

I can't just add the `cd` line into the script because I need to distribute this and it needs to work no matter where on the computer it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a bash script:

```sh
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

will cd into the directory containing the script.